# Foundation Cli css - primordials is not defined Foundation-cli

Tags: css, npm, zurb-foundation

i'm executing `sudo npm install --global foundation-cli`
Getting an error when creating foundation zurb project
[image: Foundation cli ReferenceERror: primordials is not defined]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code/errors, instead embed it directly in your post.

Comment: Images of text aren't searchable, or accessible. By including the text of the error and formatting it correctly you increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Also please do not use `sudo` for `npm install`.

Comment: thx, for clarification, becouse for a new ask, i'm giving errors :

> You have reached your question limit Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to downgrade to NodeJS 10, the issue is known and happens on newer NodeJS versions in the `natives` package. Or try to rebuild your packages with `npm rebuild --force`

Quick Google and GitHub searches lead to the same solution.

Comment: i'm using node v12.8.0

Comment: "You have to downgrade to NodeJS 10". Please downgrade to 10. The version of `natives` that is in your project is not compatible with NodeJS 12.

Comment: i can solved with
1) npm rebuild node-sass
2) npm run build

i go to fix my package.json for run automatically npm install & npm rebuild node-sass & npm run build 

installing all module normally this fix all error for modules, another option creating an webpack.config.json for run an auto install dependecy 

this problem has considered when i change of unix or another operative system 
an run npm install for all dependecies